# PHP Redirect to a Root PHP File

Tags: php, redirect, directory

I have a form submission function and upon submission I want the user to be redirected to a view. But my redirect is adding something on the link.

My Directory System is Like this.

```
exercise3/
         css/
          js/
          inc/
             /Controller
                OperatorController.php
             /Model
                FormModel.php
             include.php
fillup.php
fillup-view.php
```

My OperatorController.php handles form sumbmission processing which is located at exercise3\inc\Controller\OperatorController.php . If form is success I have this

```
if ($result == '1')
        {

            header("Location: ../fillup-view.php/");      
        }
```

so basically I'm want the user to be redirected to exercise3/fillup-view.php
The problem is it is directed at

```
 /exercise3/inc/fillup-view.php/
```

it is inserting "inc" is there something wrong in

```
header("Location: ../fillup-view.php/");
```

.. is not pointing to root but on inc? 
Thanks!

Comment: `../` means `inc` folder ... where's the surprise? Maybe `/` without dots. or `../../`

Comment: Try header("Location: ../../fillup-view.php/");

Comment: /fillup-view.php is that it?

Comment: use this `header("Location: ../../fillup-view.php")`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try something like this.
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'controller_name', 'action' => 'fillup-view'));

Comment: I'm not using a "REAL" MVC Framework :) It's just I'm naming the folders that way :)